# Reproducing Spotify playlist with "devices available" programmatically

Tags: spotify, chromecast

Is there any way to reproduce Spotify playlist **programmatically** in devices available on my network such as Chromcast Audio?

Looking for code examples.

**Update**: 
The idea is to do this:
Change from phone or windows app to Chromecast programmatically and reproduce a playlist.

[image]

Comment: And how does that look like? You shouldn't assume readers all have that app on their phones.

Comment: Check the image :-)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write your MediaRouteChooserDialog and write your own MediaRouteDialogFactory and register that. You can find sample codes in [CCL](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/tree/master/src/com/google/android/libraries/cast/companionlibrary/cast/dialog/video) and in the standard chooser [dialog](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/b19bf0bf4276342a8e7b64370088b3614d31c20c/v7/mediarouter/src/android/support/v7/app/MediaRouteChooserDialog.java).

Comment: This is very useful info. Thanks. However, I would probably have to relay on Spotify API as I'm indicating it to stream music to a particular devices.